# $A$ retract of $X$ and $X$ contractible implies $A$ contractible.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have constructed the following proof of the statement and have some questions (a question) about the correctness of the proof:

**Statement:**

> $A$ retract of $X$ and $X$ contractible implies $A$ contractible.
>
> ---

**Proof:**

I make the following observations:

- Since $X$ is contractible we have $1_{X} \simeq constant $. This follows from a proposition that a space $X$ is contractible if and only if $1_{X}$ is nullhomotopic.
- $A$ retract of $X$ gives us that there exists a map $r: X \rightarrow A$ such that $r\circ i = 1_{A}$ where $i:A\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion map.

Now I conclude:

$1_{A} = r\circ i = r \circ 1_{X} \circ i \simeq r \circ constant \circ i$

Since $r \circ constant \circ i$ is a constant map we have that $1_{A}$ is nullhomotopic and thus *we have $A$ is contractible.*

---

**Questions:**

- Is this proof correct?
- I use that $f \simeq f_{1}$ implies $g \circ f \simeq g\circ f_{1}$. Is this true? I think it makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof that retract of contractible space is contractible](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/proof-that-retract-of-contractible-space-is-contractible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write $r\circ 1_X\circ i\simeq r\circ \text{constant}\circ i,$ then you implicitly mean that the homotopy is $r\circ F\circ(i\times 1_I),$ so your proof is correct.

In general, if $f_1\simeq f_2$ by $F$ then $g\circ f_1\simeq g\circ f_2$ by $g\circ F,$ and $f_1\circ h\simeq f_2\circ h$ by $F\circ(h\times 1_I).$

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative proof, demanding some familiarity with categories.

The contractible objects in category $\mathbf{Top}$ are exactly the
terminal objects in category $\mathbf{hTop}$. If $X$ is a terminal object in $\mathbf{hTop}$, then for every object $Y$ the 
homset $\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,X\right)$ contains exactly one arrow.
Let us denote this arrow by $\left[c\right]$. Then homset $\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,A\right)$
contains arrow $\left[r\right]\left[c\right]$. Now let $\left[f\right]\in\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,A\right)$.
Then $\left[i\right]\left[f\right]\in\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,X\right)$
so $\left[i\right]\left[f\right]=\left[c\right]$. Then we find $\left[f\right]=\left[r\right]\left[i\right]\left[f\right]=\left[r\right]\left[c\right]$
demonstrating that $\left[r\right]\left[c\right]$ is the only element
of $\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,A\right)$. Proved is now that $A$ is terminal
in $\mathbf{hTop}$, hence contractible in $\mathbf{Top}$.

In my view this proof is a good demonstration of 'the joy of cats'.

---

Later: A bit shorter:

$\left[\right]:\mathbf{Top}\rightarrow\mathbf{hTop}$ is a functor
and functors respect retractions (=arrows that have a right-inverse). So if $r:X\rightarrow A$ is a retraction
in $\mathbf{Top}$ then $\left[r\right]:X\rightarrow A$ is a retraction
in $\mathbf{hTop}$.

If $\left[r\right]:X\rightarrow A$ is a retraction and
$X$ is terminal then $\left[r\right]$ is an isomorphism, hence $A$
is terminal. (This is true in every category, but to maintain the line of the proof I keep on using the notation $\left[r\right]$.)

(Proof: some $\left[s\right]:A\rightarrow X$ exists with $\left[r\right]\left[s\right]=1$;
then $\left[s\right]\left[r\right]:X\rightarrow X$ and the identity
is the only endomorphism here, so $\left[s\right]\left[r\right]=1$.)

Comment: Leuk! (=nice in Dutch). Can you suggest some source where homotopy theory or $hTop$ or algebraic topology are developed using the language of categories?

Comment: @magma Ja, leuk hè. Lekker kort! Sorry, I cannot help you with any source. I just found out myself.

Comment: Jammer! (what a pity!) Check my profile if you like to en-joy the cats with a Computer Algebra System (Mathematica).

Comment: @magma I allready did that. However I have no Mathematica on my computer, wich is required for this.

Comment: you may contact me per email if you would like to discuss this further

Comment: @magma Well, then whats in it for me if I have no Mathematica? I do not intend to buy that. But I don't exclude yet that you see possibities that I don't see. And another thing: how do get your e-mail adress? I can imagine that you don't want to expose that here. Is there a way here for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10769/discussion-between-drhab-and-magma)

Comment: @StefanH. No, they are not. Take singleton {0} as domain (contractible). In hTop there are 2 distinct arrows to {0,1} (equipped with discrete topology). The maps are not homotopic. The empty space is the (unique) initial object here.

Comment: Whoops. I guess I was thinking about basepoint-preserving maps, when I wrote that. They are only initial in $\mathbf{hTop}_*$ However, what is true is that retracts of initial objects are initial.